# RDP from more than one router

Tags: windows, rdp

I'm trying to get my server to accept RDP from a different router/gateway than the server is set up on.  If I change the gateway on the server to the router forwarding RDP then it connects but if I switch back to the original router, it won't accept the trafic from the RDP router.  Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: Did you forward port 3389 on the new router to the server?

Comment: Yes, but my server will not accept it unless it I set the forwarding RDP router as the gateway on the server.

Comment: Do you want to have *all* RDP go through the second router, or do you want to be able to RDP via *both* routers?

Comment: I'm not doing RDP through both, just the second one, which is NOT the gateway router for the server.

Answer (score 4):

I gather you have two routers connecting to different ISPs and you want incomining connections from both to successfully work?  You either need a specialized router for this, one that supports dual-wan, or you need to setup NAT on the incoming connections, as the connections hit the RDP server they appear to come from the router instead of some external address.  The challenge here is that low-end routers that you would see in a SOHO don't have any facilities in the user interface to accomplish this, most dual-wan routers have this facility built-in.

When your RDP sends reply packets the routing table will be used to choose which router to forward to.  NAT on the incoming connections can fix this since each router adjusting the packets so the source address/port is the LAN side ip address of the router.  Since the router will be on the local network the RDP server will reply to the correct router.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I need my server to recognize RDP traffic from the second router.

Comment: So I need to set up NAT on the server then?

Comment: No, it probably needs to be done on the routers.  If you can't setup incoming NAT on your routers, then you probably need to replace your routers with something more flexible.

Comment: They are capable.  I will experiment with that. thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I have a Verizon FIOS/ActionTec router model MI424WR with static NAT.  What would be the configuration to get the above scenario to work?

Comment: It doesn't appear like that router has the required ability to do what I am suggesting.  You probably need to be looking at a multi-wan router to combine things.